# How to call jquery script inside echo of php

Tags: php, jquery

In following code i want to insert a jquery script: I have mentioned the space in code where i want to insert the jquery code:

```
<?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $stu  = $row['stu_id'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['stu_id']);
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$no.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['student_id'].'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_id[]" value='.$row['student_id'].'>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">'.$row['student_name'].'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_name[]" value='.$row['student_name'].'>
                    <td>'."<input name='obtmarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control'  type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>

                    <td>'."<input name='percentage[]' placeholder='' class='form-control'  type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>

 Here i want to add jquery script

                    <input type="hidden" name="class[]" value='.$row['class'].'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_date[]" value='.$TestDate.'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_subject[]" value='.$SelectSubject.'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_type[]" value='.$TestType.'>

                </tr>';

            $total += $row['stu_id'];
            $no++;

        }

        ?>
```

JQuery script is as under:-

```
<script>
var SecondNumVal = "20";

function ShowPercentage() {

    var $inputs = $('input');

    // get values
    var firstNumVal = $inputs.eq(0).val();


    // compute something
    var percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100;

    // set value
    $inputs.eq(1).val(parseInt(percentVal) + '%').prop('readonly', true);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mysecondnumber').on('change blur', ShowPercentage);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you aware that PHP first gets compiled and then only jQuery gets loaded or executed? There won't be any PHP seen when it comes to jQuery.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman i am new in coding and wants some help of yours.. infact i have tried the jquery separately by calling two input boxes (its working find) and now wants to include this jquery code in my actual coding which as above. can you please guide....Sincerest Regards.

Comment: if you want to add a script that gets called by user input (filling a form, changing a selector, etc) after the page loads, you can do so easily, but my advice would be to place it at the bottom of your code, not in the middle, and then just call it. You don't need to use PHP at all to do this. This would require some code changes but nothing too tricky

Comment: Are you just struggling with the syntax, getting that JavaScript code “into” the echo statement? Instead of dealing with the necessary escaping of the different quote styles, you better simply leave the PHP parser for that. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: I don't think this will work as you intend. `$inputs` refer to the inputs in the whole document, not each `tr`, and even then `$inputs.eq(0)` would grab `student_id`. Can you describe in more detail what you want to do ?

Comment: @msg actually the jQuery calculates percentage. User will enter marks in obtmarks which is an html inputbox and i want that jQuery will automatically fill the percentage of that obtmarks in percentage (which is also an html inputbox) when user presses the tab. In a separate file jQuery script running fine with two input boxes, but i want it  add in my actual code which i have pasted above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

php will get executed **before rendering the page**. Jquery has role only after page render. If you want to add custom function to every field, use a class and select all elements with that class and do the stuff there. You can write script anywhere in the page and it will get executed. No need to add into the place where it needs to be executed.

Comment: while a script can be added mostly anywhere in the page, it's best practice to place scripts at the bottom of it (as near as possible to the closing `</BODY>` tag, so as to reduce the impact in page rendering times. This is not to say that the script cannot be placed anywhere (because it can), just that it's not necessarily a good idea to actually place them anywhere :)

Comment: that is true and its good practice to use the script at the bottom of the page. I just want to let Akhtar know that its possible.

Comment: @golwin thanks alot for guidance. Can you please further guide that how can i call jquery function in <td>'."<input name='percentage[]' placeholder='' class='form-control'  type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>.

Comment: just call $(".form-control"), you will get all elements with 'form-control' class or add a custom class and access those elements.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, you don't need to include the script in each row for it to work. Also, as I've mentioned in the comments, `$inputs` refer to the inputs in the whole document, not each `tr`, and even if it did, `$inputs.eq(0)` would then refer to the first `input` in the row, which is `student_id`. 
Simplified example (added new classes to the `input` and changed percentage to `type="text"`), you just have to call this script on `$.ready`

```js
// Delegate on the table to listen for changes in obtmark fields.
// Less event listeners to attach
$('#marks').on('change', '.obtmark', function() {
  var SecondNumVal = "20";

  $mark = $(this)
  var firstNumVal = $mark.val();
  // Find the tr this control is in and the corresponding percentage field
  $pct = $mark.closest('tr').find('.percentage')
  percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100
  pct = parseInt(percentVal) + '%';
  $pct.val(pct).attr('readonly', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="marks">
  <tr>
    <td><input name='obtmarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control obtmark' type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='percentage[]' placeholder='' class='form-control percentage' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name='obtmarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control obtmark' type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='percentage[]' placeholder='' class='form-control percentage' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name='obtmarks[]' placeholder='' class='form-control obtmark' type='number' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
    <td><input name='percentage[]' placeholder='' class='form-control percentage' type='text' required='required' style='width: 120px;'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: its working fine now. But when i am posting percentage in mysql table its inserting '0' in all fields.

Comment: @Akhtar how's your column defined ? I changed the datatype of the `input` to `string` since it contained the symbol "%". You'll have to strip it out.

Comment: i have removed "%" ..but it is still storing 0 in mysql table. The column in mysql table is defined as "decimal type".

Comment: @Akhtar have you checked that you are actually getting a value ? Also try running it through `intval` before inserting, just in case.