# how to repeat jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery

In the following code i am accessing student-ID and student-Name from mysql table and offering user to enter obtained marks. When a user input marks the jQuery function automatically calculates the percentage and shows it in next inputbox which is percentage. There are 20 students whom marks have to be entered. Every thing is working fine for me but jQuery only calculating first input box value and showing result in percentage, in rest of 19 columns its showing nothing. Code is as  under:-

```
<table id = "result" class="data-table">

        <caption class="title"></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>    
                <th><strong>Sr.No.</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Student ID</strong></th>
                <th align="center"><strong>Student Name</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Obtained Marks</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Percentage</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Grade</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><strong>Remarks</strong></th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $stu  = $row['stu_id'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['stu_id']);
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$no.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['student_id'].'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_id[]" value='.$row['student_id'].'>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">'.$row['student_name'].'</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_name[]" value='.$row['student_name'].'>
                    <td>'."<input name='obtmarks[]' placeholder='' type='number' value='' class='1' id='mysecondnumber' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>

                    <td>'."<input name='obtpercentage[]' placeholder='' type='percentage' value='' class='1' onclick='ShowPercentage()' id='mypercenttextbox ' style='width: 120px;'>".'</td>


                    <input type="hidden" name="class[]" style="text-align: center;" value='.$row['class'].'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_date[]" value='.$TestDate.'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_subject[]" align="center" value='.$SelectSubject.'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="test_type[]" align="center" value='.$TestType.'>

                </tr>';

            $total += $row['stu_id'];
            $no++;

        }

        ?>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is jQuery script:-

```
<script>
var SecondNumVal = "20";

function ShowPercentage() {

    var $inputs = $('input');
    // get values
    var firstNumVal = $inputs.eq(3).val();
    // compute something
    var percentVal = (firstNumVal / SecondNumVal) * 100;
    // set value
    $inputs.eq(4).val(parseInt(percentVal) + '%').prop('readonly', true);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mysecondnumber').on('change blur', ShowPercentage);
});
</script>
```

I want jQuery to calculate percentage of all 20 entries.

Comment: ID's are meant to be unique.

Comment: Don't use same id on same page.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52742091/edit) then click the `[<>]` snippet editor. Add HTML (no PHP) for more than one student and paste the script into the script pane.

Comment: What you want is to use the class and relative addressing: `$('.mysecondnumber').on("change blur",ShowPercentage)` using `firstNumVal = $(this).closest("tr").find("[name='obtmarks[]']").val()`

Comment: @mplungjan not working

Comment: @mplungjan now even not calculating first percentage

Comment: Is this an [assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740405)?

Comment: @msg no. I am learning php. I came to this problem when i made an html form which shows 20 students with their ID and Name and user will put obtained marks against all student and submit form, i want that when user input marks for 1st student and press tab than in input box next to obtained marks automatically calculate percentage, when user enters obtained marks for 2nd student than it do same and so on for 20 students.

Comment: @msg now above code running fine, it is calculating 1st student percentage but not rest of 19 studens..can you please make changes in my code.

Comment: See linked question. I just answered this **exact question** 20 minutes ago.

Comment: @msg thanks. but please see if you can help in this code. Regards

Comment: My code was an example - since you have not posted html I could not test it. You have to make a little effort yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a class - your IDs are being duplicated which is invalid
2. Do not have numeric classes
3. Don't echo
4. Don't concatenate HTML
5. use proper quotes in value=""
6. Don't have input fields outside the cells

---

```
?><tr>
    <td><?= $no ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['student_id'] ?></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="student_id[]" value="<?= $row['student_id'] ?>">
    <td style="text-align: left;"><?= $row['student_name'] ?><input type="hidden" name="student_name[]" value="<?= $row['student_name'] ?>"></td>
    <td><input name="obtmarks[]" placeholder="" type="number" value="" class="obtmarks" style="width: 120px;"></td>
    <td><input name="obtpercentage[]" placeholder="" type="percentage" value="" class="mypercenttextbox" style="width: 120px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="class[]" style="text-align: center;" value="<?= $row['class'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="test_date[]" value="<?= $TestDate ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="test_subject[]" align="center" value="<?= $SelectSubject ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="test_type[]" align="center" value="<?= $TestType ?>"></td>

</tr>
```

Then you can do

```
$('.obtmarks').on("change blur",ShowPercentage)
```

using

```
var obtval = $(this).val(); // obtmarks
var myPercent = $(this).closest("tr").find(".mypercenttextbox").val();
```